# Is it possible to reprogram a keyboard?

Tags: embedded, hardware

I mean the real USB keyboard, not a software keyboard driver.

I know that keybords differ, but in general is it easy/possible to reprogram / rewire it?
Maybe there are models that are easier to do that?

And yes, I can use soldering iron / hardware flash reprogrammer.

Comment: You could do pull off all the keys and swap em around. Otherwise I'm guessing you'll need to find the chip inside (if they use em) and find a programmer for it.

Comment: what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, no. Most keyboards that you find have a small bit of brains and a switch matrix and not much else. They have just enough brains to communicate over USB while scanning their switch matrix. The entire mess is in one mask-programmed chip that you can't change the programming of.

There are a few keyboards out there that do things like key remapping or macro programming in the keyboard, but they are pretty rare and/or pretty expensive. And, in my experience, pretty damned annoying when you accidentally hit the 'program macro' key accidentally.

You could, in theory, tear akeyboard apart, remove it's existing brains, install a micro-controller and write code to send whatever codes you want to the host when a given point on the switch matrix is hit. You'll need to work out what traces are what on the switch matrix, and you'll need to write/find micro-controller code to talk USB. And don't forget that a switch matrix is susceptible to ghosting effects (one keypress masks others), so don't try to put things like shift, control, alt on keys that are subject to ghosting.

If you don't/can't do the micro-controller work yourself, you could use something like an [ipac](http://www.ultimarc.com/ipac1.html) (it's the micro-controller part that I just described) to do the job, but you'll have to get something that understands a switch matrix.

Answer (score 3):

For some keyboards it is possible, as a recent [hack of an Apple keyboard](http://deobfuscated.blogspot.com/2009/08/mac-keyboard-firmware-rootkit-unveiled.html) revealed.

Comment: The blog article linked in the answer seems to be gone.  Here's a link to a Blackhat presentation on the topic: http://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-usa-09/CHEN/BHUSA09-Chen-RevAppleFirm-PAPER.pdf

Answer (score 2):

yes. you need to remove the manufacturer's controller and wire in a programmable keyboard controller. the better controllers contain a rom to hold the key matrix. (essential keyboard functions and raw scancodes are segregated and remain untouched). a convenient windows app is used to create the matrix, then compile to a binary, then flash the rom.

search: FlexMatrix SK5100/SK5101 i think it does macros too! =D